# Anonymous delegates don't seem to enforce type-checking

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function

I've put together a small code-sample below (Currently in C# 3.5 but would also like to know if the answer is any different in C# 4.0)

I have three simple delegates, and three simple functions ... No problem here, everything compiles as expected, and will not compile if I accidentally try to link delegate A with Method B etc (wrong number of parameters).

What I'm struggling to understand is why the anonymous functions seem happy to be linked to all three of the named delegates

```
public class Foo
{
   public delegate void del_TestWithNoParams();
   public delegate void del_TestWithThreeInts(int x, int y, int z);
   public delegate void del_TestWithIntPtr(IntPtr ptr);

   public void DoStuff()
   {
      //All OK so Far ... Code will not compile if I mix these up
      del_TestWithNoParams d1 =
         TestWithNoParams; d1();
      del_TestWithThreeInts d2 =
         TestWithThreeInts; d2(2, 4, 8);
      del_TestWithIntPtr d3 =
         TestWithIntPtr; d3(new IntPtr(0x1234567));

      //Why do these compile
      del_TestWithNoParams d4_nocompile =
         delegate { Console.WriteLine("AnonymousDel d4"); };
      del_TestWithThreeInts d5_nocompile =
         delegate { Console.WriteLine("AnonymousDel d5"); };
      del_TestWithIntPtr d6_nocompile =
         delegate { Console.WriteLine("AnonymousDel d6"); };

      // Edit 1 goes here
   }

     public void TestWithNoParams()
     { Console.WriteLine("NoParams"); }
     public void TestWithThreeInts(int x, int y, int z)
     { Console.WriteLine("Ints: {0},{1},{2}", x, y, z); }
     public void TestWithIntPtr(IntPtr ptr)
     { Console.WriteLine("IntPtr: 0x{0:X8}", ptr.ToInt32()); }

 }
```

Also (just to give you a complete runnable app...)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var f = new Foo();
     f.DoStuff();
     Console.WriteLine("Done"); Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

---

**Edit 1: Using Lambda Methods**

```
 //This work as expected - and fail to build if I get the parameter-count wrong.
 del_TestWithNoParams d7 =
   (() => Console.WriteLine("Lambda NoParams"));
 del_TestWithThreeInts d8 =
   ((a, b, c) => Console.WriteLine("Lambda Ints: {0},{1},{2}", a, b, c));
 del_TestWithIntPtr d9 =
   ((ptr) => Console.WriteLine("Lambda IntPtr: 0x{0:X8}", ptr.ToInt32()));
 Test(d7, d8, d9);
```

Simple Helper Function:

```
private void Test(del_TestWithNoParams del_A, del_TestWithThreeInts del_B, del_TestWithIntPtr del_C)
{
   del_A();
   del_B(2, 4, 8);
   del_C(new IntPtr(0x1234567));
}
```

... Would you agree that this is a **better** method to write the same code ???

---

**Edit #2 - Summary of Answers**

I realise that (whichever way I write the code), the generated IL byte-code is still Type-Safe..

As with many things in C#, named-delegates, anonymous delegates, and lambda methods each have their own place, and there is a balance between "code-readability", "compiler-expansion-of-code" and the suitability for the individual application being written.

The replies below have helped answer the question, and show that the compiler is really doing something similar to the following.

1 - It will NOT allow me to make this mistake

```
//del_TestWithIntPtr d_mistake_A =
//   delegate(int x,int y,int z) { Console.WriteLine(x + y + z); };
```

2 - The "compiler inferring the types" is expanding the delegate (e.g. d5_nocompile) out to

```
del_TestWithThreeInts d_clearer_3P =
delegate(int x, int y, int z) { Console.WriteLine(x + y + z); };
```

3 - It is POSSIBLE to make a mistake (which is still valid code)

```
del_TestWithThreeInts d_EasyToMakeMistake =
delegate { Console.WriteLine("Oops - forgot to do anything with params"); };
// (this is really :- delegate (int x, int y, int z) {...} )
```

4 - However, when re-written as a lambda expression, it is slightly more obvious when looking through the code later (or to another developer)

```
del_TestWithThreeInts d_LessEasyToMakeMistake =
((x, y, z) => Console.WriteLine("Still POSSIBLE to make mistake, but more obvious"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, This enforces the type checking. It will take default values if the params are not supplied for anonymous function when assigning to a delegate.

Refer C# language spec(§6.5), it states

> An anonymous-method-expression or
>   lambda-expression is classified as an
>   anonymous function (§7.14). The
>   expression does not have a type but
>   can be implicitly converted to a
>   compatible delegate type or expression
>   tree type. Specifically, a delegate
>   type D is compatible with an anonymous
>   function F provided:
>
> - If F contains an anonymous-function-signature, then D
>     and F have the same number of
>     parameters.
> - If F does not contain an anonymous-function-signature, then D
>     may have zero or more parameters of
>     any type, as long as no parameter of D
>     has the out parameter modifier.

If you compile Your source code & Open it in **Reflector** (in framework 1.1 setup), you ll see the compiler automatically assigns default parameters to the Anonymous methods that doesnt have the param list.

```
 del_TestWithNoParams d4_nocompile = (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate40 != null) ? CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate40 : (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate40 = new del_TestWithNoParams(Program.<Main>b__27));
    del_TestWithThreeInts d5_nocompile = (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate41 != null) ? CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate41 : (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate41 = new del_TestWithThreeInts(Program.<Main>b__28));
    del_TestWithIntPtr d6_nocompile = (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate42 != null) ? CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate42 : (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate42 = new del_TestWithIntPtr(Program.<Main>b__29));
```

And b__28(method for the delegate del_TestWithThreeInts) will be something like this

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static void <Main>b__28(int, int, int)
{
    Console.WriteLine("AnonymousDel d5");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When anonymous methods are used, what is really happening is that a class is created with a property defined for each of the parameters of the delegate.

If you don't pass parameter values, default ones are used.

Comment: I had forgotten how dangerous anonymous delegates could be ... Would you agree that from a coding perspective, it would be "safer" (to prevent accidental "wrong-typing") to use the equivalent lambda expressions (as per Edit #1)

Comment: I don't see how could you get type safe problems, if you use a parameter of a different type the code would not compile.
The lambda syntax is just a matter of preference, i think is shorter and i prefer that, but i can't see benefits related to wrong typing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify paramters for anonymous methods created with the `delegate` keyword, the parameters are inferred automatically by the compiler, so it doesn't matter what the delegate signature is